# Using a 'for' loop to assign values to variables and using variable names in that function

Tags: c, arrays, loops, variables, assign

I have a for loop that gets data from a slave i2c device. The device has 3-axis and I need to read the high and low bits of each axis for a total of six measurements, and then combine them into one variable. I started off just making a function to get the data and passing the slave address and sub-register address to that function, but now I'm integrating a second slave device which means I would need to call that function 12 times and would then have to the bit combination in the main or do some pass by reference stuff to another function.

Instead, I've made a function that loops through all the data registers and I want to assign it to my variable names in that loop and then do the bit combination in that same function. I have an array of variable names and a pointer to those names that gets iterated along with the data sub-register address.

```
char data_name[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'};

char *array_name_pointer[7];
array_name_pointer[i] = &data_name[i];
uint8_t sub_data_reg = 0x00;

for(i=0; i<6; i++){

    if (HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, Comp_Addr , sub_data_reg, sizeof(sub_data_reg), (uint8_t*)(&array_name_pointer), sizeof(data_name[i]), HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK){
        Error_Handler();
        printf("Could not get raw data \n\r");
    }

    printf("%c has value %d \n\r", (data_name[i]), sub_data_reg);
    sub_data_reg ++;
}

xl = a;
xh = b;
yl = c;
yh = d;
zl = e;
zh = f;

printf("xl: %d xh: %d yl: %d yh:%d \n\r", xl, xh, yl, yh);

float x_Raw = ((xh<<8)|xl);
float y_Raw = ((yh<<8)|yl);
float z_Raw = ((zh<<8)|zl);`
```

my first `printf` line prints a = 0 and so on correctly, but when I change the variable name to `xl` it gives me an error where `a, b, …` have not been used before. I suspect this is because they are of type char, so I tried changing them to type int. When I did that, the values of xl, xh, and so forth was always `0`.

How do I assign the measured values to these variables? Is it good practice to do it this way?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to show all your declarations and the exact error that you are getting.

Comment: The only other declarations are global declarations of xl=0, xh=0, … and a local declaration of int i =0 for my loop counter. I'm not getting any errors, its just not working.

Comment: Please, show the exact error message, and not your interpretation about it.  You are making a serious mistake considering that the `char` literals `'a'`, `'b'`... are variable names or that you can somehow convert them into variable names.  That's erroneous and makes it impossible to guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: Another user solved it! Please see bellow for the solution, and my description above which describes what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The character constants `'a'`, `'b'`. etc. that you have used to initialize `data_name[]` have nothing whatsoever to do with the variables named `a`, `b`, etc.

Also, in this code:

```
char *array_name_pointer[7];
array_name_pointer[i] = &data_name[i];
```

It is not clear what the value of `i` is at this point. If `i` is outside the range 0 to 6, this array access will be out of range, leading to *undefined behavior*.

In this code:

```
    if (HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, Comp_Addr , sub_data_reg, sizeof(sub_data_reg), (uint8_t*)(&array_name_pointer), sizeof(data_name[i]), HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK){
```

The `array_name_pointer` array of `char *` is being used as a buffer of `uint8_t` values. Assuming a pointer is 4 bytes long, then since `i` loops from 0 to 5 inclusive (terminating when `i == 6`), this will clobber any pointer values held in `array_name_pointer[0]` and `array_name_pointer[1]`.

This code:

```
    printf("%c has value %d \n\r", (data_name[i]), sub_data_reg);
    sub_data_reg ++;
```

will print a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, etc. The 0, 1 and 2 are not the data read from the I2C registers. They are just the indices of the I2C registers being read.

In this code:

```
xl = a;
xh = b;
yl = c;
yh = d;
zl = e;
zh = f;
```

The variables `a`, `b`, etc. probably have never been initialized or assigned, resulting in the compiler warnings.

---

What you probably need to do is read the I2C registers into an array of `uint8_t` and extract the values from that array:

```
    uint8_t reg_vals[6];
    uint8_t sub_data_reg = 0x00;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, Comp_Addr , sub_data_reg, sizeof(sub_data_reg), &reg_vals[i], sizeof(reg_vals[i]), HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK){
            Error_Handler();
            printf("Could not get raw data \n\r");
        }

        printf("%c has value %d \n\r", data_name[i], reg_vals[i]);
        sub_data_reg ++;
    }

    xl = reg_vals[0];
    xh = reg_vals[1];
    yl = reg_vals[2];
    yh = reg_vals[3];
    zl = reg_vals[4];
    zh = reg_vals[5];
```

If the I2C device supports reading a block of registers with auto-incremented register addresses, you could change the above code to call `HAL_I2C_Mem_Read` once instead of 6 times:

```
    uint8_t reg_vals[6];
    uint8_t sub_data_reg = 0x00;

    if (HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, Comp_Addr , sub_data_reg, sizeof(sub_data_reg), &reg_vals[0], 6 * sizeof(reg_vals[0]), HAL_MAX_DELAY) != HAL_OK){
        Error_Handler();
        printf("Could not get raw data \n\r");
    }
    sub_data_reg += 6;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%c has value %d \n\r", data_name[i], reg_vals[i]);
    }

    xl = reg_vals[0];
    xh = reg_vals[1];
    yl = reg_vals[2];
    yh = reg_vals[3];
    zl = reg_vals[4];
    zh = reg_vals[5];
```